# Same values are treated as different when comparing by !==

Tags: php

Jquery captures field input and POSTs to .php through AJAX. The fields are 'password' and 'confirmpassword'

PHP will call a method of an object with $_POST['password']  and $_POST['confirmpassword'] as arguments

The method has the following check amongst others:

```
} else if ($password !== $confirmPassword){
        $response = 'Passwords do not match';
        return $response;

        }
```

Disregarding of what I input the response is ALWAYS "Passwords do not match".

I print values to error_log() just to be on the safe side and they are same, i.e. no modification happens.

Does anyone have any idea what is this behavior?

UPD 1

I did some more testing and it seems that the !== check works fine BEFORE variable are passed as arguments to a method of an object. However, after I pass these values as arguments to a class (added through 'require' to the page) something terrible happens...

UPD 2

Here is full code:

a) Jquery

```
var signupRegister = function(){
    var username  = $('#signup-username').val();
    var email  = $('#signup-email').val();
    var password  = $('#signup-password').val();
    var confirmPassword  = $('#signup-confirmpassword').val();

    console.log(password);
    console.log(confirmPassword);
    var data = {action:'signup', username:username, email:email, password:password, confirmPassword:confirmPassword};

$.ajax({
    url: 'php/ajaxhandler.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response.msg);
    }
});
```

};

b) Ajax handler (note that commented out code works!)

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'signup'){   //REQUEST 1: validate client input and add player to DB
    $player = new Player();
    $db = new Database();

/*
    if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['confirmPassword']){
        $json['msg'] = 'mismatch';
        echo json_encode($json);
    } else {
        $json['msg'] = 'match';
        echo json_encode($json);

    }

*/


    $result = $player -> validateAndSignup($db, $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['confirmPassword']);
    if ($result){
        $json['msg'] = $result;
        echo json_encode($json);
    } else {
        error_log('Error in $player -> validateAndSignup()');
    }
```

c) the actual method of the Player class

```
public function validateAndSignup($db, $username, $email, $password, $confirmPassword){     
    error_log($password);
    error_log($confirmPassword);
    if($username === "" || $email == "" || $password = "" || $confirmPassword === ""){
        $response = 'Username, email or password missing';
        return $response;       

        } else if (strcmp($password, $confirmPassword) !== 0){
        $response = 'Passwords do not match';
        return $response;

        } else if(preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $username)){
            $response = 'Invalid characters in username';
            return $response;

        }


}
```

Comment: In question you wrote $_POST['password'] but in your code i noticed that you are using $password. Did you initialise `$password` variable

Comment: @ georoot  I use the $_POST[] directly as an argument

Comment: i got that after reading your edit. I am guessing you are somehow changing variable data in the require script. Can you post that script over here ? Also paste a dump of the variables before and after the require

Comment: @georoot I have pasted the code. Is there an easy way to do var_dump() when I am supposed to return AJAX and not echoing anything on the page (I am not even visiting the page).

Comment: `echo` `password` and `confirmPassword` inside the block where you match the passwords and see what values do they hold if not the same. Also just a hunch try replacing `!==` with `!=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding your full code the problem is clear:

In this line

```
if($username === "" || $email == "" || $password = "" || $confirmPassword === ""){
```

**you are setting `$password` to `""`.**

Checking a empty string against the `$confirmedPassword` does not match.

**Bonus:**
Use `isset()` to check if a string is empty instead of `===`. ([Explanation here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php))

Comment: OMG I feel so embarrassed now :$ Thanx a million! need go to bed and take some rest...

Answer (score 1):

**Checking strings directly should not be done but instead you can use `strcmp()` to compare two strings. `strcmp()` is binary safe.**

1. `strcmp("StackOverflow", "StackOverflow")` will return `0` as the strings are equal.
2. `strcmp("stackoverflow", "StackOverflow")` will return `<0` if the first argument is less than the second argument and `>0` if the second argument is bigger.

In your case you would want to do something like this:

```
if(strcmp($password, $confirmedPassword) === 0) {
    echo "Password are equal!";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :( I think something happens to the values when they are being sent as arguments. There is no other code which touches them on the way.

Comment: @Vadimster then I would check if there is a space appended or prepended.  Or any other char that would mess with this.

Comment: I have added the code to illustrate. This is the only code which handles the values. There is actually no other code as this is all I have done so far.